# Can't generate a working ssh public / private key pair for new user

Tags: encryption, ssh, key, private, public

I'm trying to add a new user to my Ubuntu system and give them SSH access, using public/private key to log in. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Used putty gen to generate a public / private key pair. Then copied the public key into their homedir/.ssh/authorized_keys. But when I load the private key into Pageant in my windows session and try to use putty to get in, I am getting "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available".

The funny thing is, If i put the same public key in the existing user's ./.ssh/authorized_keys file, I can log on using that user. This was set up by someone before me who I can't contact now though, so I don't know what the difference is.

If I check the etc/ssh/sshd_config file, the AuthorizedKeysFile line is commented out.
    #AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

BUt even if I put it back in and restart ssh service it still doesn't work (though I didn't think would solve it because why would the current user work)

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: When I have this problem its almost always permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `sshd` daemon's error messages in your system log (`auth.log` or `security.log` or some such).

My guess would be that the directory and/or file permissions on `.ssh` or `.ssh/authorized_keys` are too permissive (insecure) in the new user's home.  This should fix it if this is the problem:

```
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 644 .ssh/authorized_keys
```